# Gelman & Rubin convergence diagnostic for Ensemble samplers

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, convergence

### Background

The [Gelman & Rubin (1992)](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2246093?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) convergence diagnostic requires $M$ MCMC chains to be run, each starting from an over-dispersed estimate of the target population. It then computes a diagnostic based on the between and within-chain variance ([this post](http://blog.stata.com/2016/05/26/gelman-rubin-convergence-diagnostic-using-multiple-chains/) provides a good summary).

Ensemble MCMC samplers, in particular the [Goodman & Weare (2010)](http://msp.org/camcos/2010/5-1/camcos-v5-n1-p04-p.pdf) Ensemble samplers with affine invariance, use multiple *walkers*. The proposal distribution for a given walker is then generated (in effect) by the position of all the other walkers.

### Question

Ensemble samplers naturally have a number of parallel walkers. Is it (or when is it not) appropriate to use these in place of the $M$ independent chains of the Gelman & Rubin statistic to access convergence?

I have tried this out (see [this rough note](http://ga7g08.github.io/2017/02/09/The-Gelman-Rubin-Statistic-and-emcee/)) this for the [emcee](https://github.com/dfm/emcee/tree/master/emcee) implementation of the Goodman & Weare (2010) sampler with some success. However, if I use too many point, the test fails (suggests convergence when it has not converged as seen by eye). I think this is probably due to the fact the samples are not independent, but I'm unsure.

If you have any input on this I'd like to hear.

Answer (score 2):

This post is a bit old but ...

According the the emcee [documentation](https://emcee.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/autocorr/):

> "you should not compute the G–R statistic using multiple chains in the
>   same emcee ensemble because the chains are not independent!"